# Open Graph on iOS: how to set expires_time on custom stories to change tense

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I followed instructions to post a custom story with Open Graph on iOS with this documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph and it worked fine.

The problem that I'm having is that I don't know how to change the tense of that post, it's always on past tense.

Reading a little bit more, it says on the reference documentation that I should set the attribute "expires_time", but I don't understand how and where.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to fix it. You have to use **setEnd_time** on an action object and that will change the tense on the published story.

```
// Create an action
id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];

// Link the object to the action
[action setObject:object forKey:@"<your object type>"];

// Set the date when this action should change the tense
[action setEnd_time:@"2014-03-08T23:23:23"];
```

The only thing is that I couldn't check what **setExpires_time** method does.